# Preventing Adobe Updater from running

Tags: updates, services

I installed Photoshop on windows 7 and don't want the adobe updater to be running always.
I tried deleting the file "AdobeUpdaterPrefs.dat" but it creates it again.
Some sources say I set the lastUpdateDate on that file to a future date, but that would mean that some process needs to be running in order to be aware of the date and choose not to update anything, but the process still runs.
Is it a service? I looked up at the services list and it's not there.
How can I prevent it from running at all? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a program in the msconfig startup tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how:

1. Go to Photoshop Help menu and select
   "Updates...".
2. When the update screen appears,
   click the Preferences button
3. Uncheck the `Automatically Check for updates` checkbox and click OK.
   (For good measures one can also uncheck all other checkboxes in the dialog.)

Answer (score 1):

AdobeUpdates is a component for all the adobe products, it can be the Abobe updater for Acrobat PDF, to make sure, start adobe acrobat go to Edit >> Preferences >> Updates and see if they are disabled